# GeoPandas Overlay Symmetric Difference: How to get the upper polygon

Tags: geopandas, overlay

I have the following code which get the difference of a pie wedges.

```
c= gp.overlay(a,b,how='symmetric_difference')
```

[image]

How to get the upper polygon?

Answer (score 2):

You just access the [`c.geometry`](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html?highlight=geometry#geodataframe) attribute.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gp

poly1 = gp.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0, 3), (3, 3), (1.5, 0), (0, 3)])])
poly2 = gp.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1, 1), (2, 1), (1.5, 0), (1, 1)])])


a = gp.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': poly1, 'a': [1]})
b = gp.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': poly2, 'b': [2]})

c = gp.overlay(a, b, how='symmetric_difference')

print(c.geometry)
```

```
0    POLYGON ((0 3, 3 3, 2 1, 1 1, 0 3))
Name: geometry, dtype: object
```

**Poly 1**

[image]

**Poly 2**

[image]

**Symmetric difference**

[image]